# Transfer of variable values between different views in SwiftUI

Tags: binding, swiftui

I'm an absolute beginner, so please indulge me.  I have looked at a number of answers, both in Stack Overflow and elsewhere, that I thought might give me a solution, but none seem to work.

What I really want to do is transfer the value of a computed variable from one view to another.

As a poor alternative, because it would take a lot of rework, I could transfer the values of the variables the computation works on to the second view (a sheet is preferred, but I could use juts another view) and do the computation there instead.

I have tried binding, ObservableObject, Observed var, Published var, but none seem to work.

The base variables used for the computation are derived from a list view in the first view using @State, so each variable is a @State var. There are seven variables each with its own array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example if you **don't want** to change the value in the `DetailView`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentCount = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(count: currentCount)) {
            Text("Tap Here!")
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var count: Int

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(count)")
    }
}
```

Here is an example if you **want** to change make the value changeable from the `DetailView`. You need to use `@Binding` in this case:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentCount = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(currentCount)")

            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(count: $currentCount)) {
                Text("Tap Here!")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var count: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(count)")

            Button(action: {
                self.count += 1
            }) {
                Text("Increase!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK.  I have tried this but now the PreviewProvider isn't working, so I can't test it to see if the variable is being dragged through. The variable in the MainView is called selectedGender and I have called the variable in the second view genderSelection. the code for the PreviewProvider looks like this: struct Insurer1View_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Insurer1View(genderSelection: $selectedGender)
    }
}

Comment: Try it on a simulator

Comment: Please accept the answer, as it solved the issue you asked.

Comment: I tried using simulator instead of preview.  I // the preview in the view showing the error first and then tried the simulator, but,  unfortunately that didn't work.  I got the Error: Missing argument for parameter 'genderSelection' in call MainPage.swift. (apologies, before I used 'MainView' above, but 'MainPage' is correct).

Comment: Part 1 ` @State private var showingSheet = false
    
    let gender = ["Male", "Female"]
    let age = ["17 to 25", "26 to 35", "36 to 50", "50 to 65", "over 65"]
    
    @State var selectedGender = 0
    @State var selectedAge = 0
    
    let genderLoads = [1.5, 1.0]
    let ageLoads = [2.5, 1.75, 1.25, 1.0, 1.25]
    
    @State var premium: Double? = 500
    
    var premiumAmount: Double {
    let premiumTotal = premium
    let genderLoad = genderLoads[selectedGender]
    let ageLoad = ageLoads[selectedAge]
    return premiumTotal! * genderLoad * ageLoad
    } `

Comment: Sorry for that mess - I read a number of posts on how to include code and none of them worked (backtrack, curly brackets, control K).

Comment: OK, after reviewing the answers above and watching numerous videos I’ve worked out how to do this. It seems to me that the calculation has to be done in the subsidiary view, which is fine.  I still have minor problems - mainly the preview for the second view where I can’t work out what to put in the parentheses. A minor issue I can live with, but any help would be appreciated. I now have an app that calculates car insurance premiums and displays the premium on the second sheet. Thanks all.

Comment: Please accept the answer and give an upvote if it helped you @Keith

Comment: I accepted the answer, but I can’t upvote because my ‘reputation’ is too low as a new user. @SwiftiSwuft

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way to do this for just one variable at a time. To do more, follow an entire tutorial on ObservedObject until you grasp that concept. I can’t make an app without ObservedObject. Or I can, but it’s like tying one hand behind my back. Anyway, for one:

In the subview, write the variable like this:

```
@Binding var passedDownList: [Item]
```

Then you call the sub view using the $ syntax like for text field and stuff.

```
MySubView(passedDownList: $myList)
```

There. The array will be in sync between the two views.